# Solve $y'(t)-y(t)-\int_0^ty''(u)y'(t-u)du=\delta(t-3)e^{2t}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I want to solve the following differential equation:
$$y'(t)-y(t)-\int_0^ty''(u)y'(t-u)du=\delta(t-3)e^{2t},\quad y(0)=y'(0)=0$$
After applying the Laplace transformation I get :
$$(s-1)L(y)(s)-s^3(L(y)(s))^2=e^{-3(s+2)}\tag{1}$$
And now I want to determine the expression of $L(y)(s)$.

I thought about considering (1) as an equation of degree $2$ with $L(y)(s)$ as an unknown and solving it. But is there an other (quicker) way?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a quadratic in $L(y)(s)$

Comment: That's what the OP said, they wanted a quicker solution

Comment: Yeah I know it's just that this is already the simplest way